# Dynamically set DataGridViewColumn default value at runtime

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control that is using to edit/update/delete records from a single table in a database.  I have overridden the DataGridView control to add the following:

```
    private int employeeID;

    public int DefaultEmployeeID
    {
        get { return employeeID; }
        set { employeeID = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnUserAddedRow(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Value = employeeID;
        base.OnUserAddedRow(e);
    }
```

When the user loads a different employee from the database, the DefaultEmployeeID attribute is then set to the employee's ID.  I know that the OnUserRowAdded event is firing properly, employeeID is being set to the correct value, and I'm positive I have the correct cell.  However, the value is still being set to 0.

What gives?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that `UserAddedRow` event fires for the *template* row (the one at the very bottom, used to add new rows to grid) - you set correct value, but for wrong row.

Simple solution to your problem:

```
protected override void OnUserAddedRow(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // get the index for "1 before last row" - the one which you in fact edit/add
    int actualRowIndex = this.Rows.Count - 2; 
    this.Rows[actualRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = employeeID;
    base.OnUserAddedRow(e);
}
```

I've run this simple example to illustrate what rows I'm talking about. As soon as user starts typing in the *template row* (left image), it becomes regular row and new template row is inserted and that's the one in event args (right image).

[image: Image illustrting which rows gets carried within event args]

Comment: This is working great with one strange side effect.  The value is only refreshed when I enter the ID cell or when I add a new row.  I'm trying to figure out which event to call but there's so damn many...

Comment: The datagridview is already bound at this point.  Perhaps I need to rebind it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview

Comment: @krs1: **[RowValidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidated.aspx)** event should be what you're looking for.