# How to change data coming from database into DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a Database with a table MASTER.
MASTER has a column Salary with Datatype MONEY.
Now, when i am getting data from database in datagridview, i want to show money column with "Rs." appended to it.
Like, if salary is 100 in database, i want to view it as Rs. 100 in my datagridview.
Fill method just copies the whole data into datagridview as it is.
How to do it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting +=
        new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(
        this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Salary")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                e.Value = String.Format("Rs. {0:F2}", e.Value);
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                e.FormattingApplied = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error- "The name 'formatting' does not occur in the current context."

Comment: @user815600 - Sorry, copy/paste error there. I corrected the example to show `e` instead of `formatting`.

Comment: Perfect. its working fine. but its giving me like, Rs. $100, but how to get rid of that $ sign. please bear with me, i am very new to this language and field

Comment: by removing currency symbol c is working, i mean making "Rs. {0:c}" to "Rs. {0}" works fine for me. But what if i want to control the decimal points. I mean, if we say c2 it gives 2 decimal places, c3 gives 3 decimal places. how to do it after removing c from the expression.

Comment: @user815600 - Sorry, `{0:C}` means format the first item (0-index) in the arguments passed to `String.Format()` in currency format. I forgot you wanted to *replace* the currency with "Rs." You can use `{0:F}` for a floating point number, which defaults to 2 decimal places. You can be more explicit by saying `{0:F2}` or `{0:0.00}` to specify at least one digit and two decimal places should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Format property of the DefaultCellStyle property of the column in question.  You can do it in a declarative manner using the Edit Columns dialog box by right-clicking on the DataGridView control.  In your case you need to set the Format property to **'Rs.'  0.00**.  Single quotes are required to escape the dot sign after the Rs.

For further information, read the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) topic on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you can modify the row adding event using [DataGridView.OnUserAddedRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onuseraddedrow.aspx)

Here is a short code. I have not tested it, but please check whether it works for you or not:

```
protected override void OnUserAddedRow(DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int actualRowIndex = this.Rows.Count - 2; 
    this.Rows[actualRowIndex].Cells["Salary"].Value = "Rs." + <Your SQL Salary>;
    base.OnUserAddedRow(e);
}
```

You can read more about this usage here: [Dynamically set DataGridViewColumn default value at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793079/dynamically-set-datagridviewcolumn-default-value-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

on DatabindingComplete you can modify that column manually (if you are working with winforms)

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["Salary"].Value = "Add your calc here";
        }
    }
```

Comment: "foreach" will work but it is just an overhead to modify a column after the DataGridView has been filled.

Comment: I agree with you. Actually I was looking for the "InitializeRow" event, but then I realized I have been working too long with Infragistics component ;)

Comment: Actually my Salary datatype in database is Money. When I am adding "Rs." to my DatagridView, it is giving error like Input format is wrong.

Comment: Then you either have to set the Format on the specific cell like @Exulted suggested further down. OR you can add a new unbound column "Salary2" in your datagrid and then swap "Salary" with "Salary2" in my suggestion

Comment: It is giving DataGridView Default Error box. Error-"Rs. 100 is not a valid value for decimal. The input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Yes, i am able to do it by adding Unbound column. can i change the column index of this unbound column and can i make Salary (original column) invisible?