# What is the fastest way to set the value of a column of SELECTEDROWS in a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have this line of code to put "TRUE" on all the first column of selectedrows:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
     row.Cells(0).Value = True
Next
```

But it takes a lot of time to put a single value to this column if the count of rows are more than a hundred.  row.Cells(0) is a boolean column, and I only need it to be set as checked/unchecked.

I have tried checking if there's a syntax that will set a value of a column, but I couldn't find anything useful from the syntax available and also from the search engine.  Hope you could help me with this one.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the `DataGridView` is databound, you shouldn't directly modify the content of the cell. Instead, you should modify the databound object. You can access that object through the `DataBoundItem` of the `DataGridViewRow` e.g. c#:

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject)dataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
obj.MyProperty = newValue;
```

Note that the bound object should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the change is reflected in the `DataGridView`
Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview)

vb.net:

```
Dim obj As MyObject = DirectCast(dataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem, MyObject)
obj.MyProperty = newValue
```

Comment: im asking in vb.net... >.<.. why do you have to copy all of the original answer's contents?

Comment: fair point I have included the vb.net for you. Was on my phone :S

Comment: that's ok.. thanks.. but im referring to SELECTED ROWS.. not CURRENTROW.. should I use the same loop again but modifying only the values from bindingsource/databound object?