# Unable to get data from child form into selected Parent DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have been stumped on a programming issue. When I right click on a cell of a DataGridView object, a context menu will show. From that context menu, a user can click an option. That option will show a form. When the user is finished, the resultant of that form will be populated in the selected cell.

Problem: How do I get the result from the child form into the selected cell? There are multiple DataGridView objects on the parent form that use the same functionality.

Code:

```
    private void commandOperation(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == dec2HexToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            frmNumFormatConv form = new frmNumFormatConv();
            if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Get data from the form into the selected cell!!!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Operational object unknown");
        }
    }

    private void cellMouseDown(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == dgvCircuit1TestSetup || sender == dgvCircuit2TestSetup)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                itsGridContextMenu.Show((DataGridView)sender, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you took a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way is to put a public property in the popup form that will return the values you want (Say RtnValue).  Then

This is an example for popup form:

```
    public string RtnValue
    {
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
```

This is your current code:

```
frmNumFormatConv form = new frmNumFormatConv();
        if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dgvalue = form.RtnValue;
            // Get data from the form into the selected cell!!!
        }
```

Comment: But how do I get the returned value into the cell of the selected DataGridView object? In the CellMouseDown method, I know which DataGridView object I am working on. When I get to the CommandOperation method, I am not able to tie which DataGridView I am coming from. That is the issue I have been trying to figure out. I may have to save the active DataGridView object as a global and clear the object after I am finished.

Comment: Are you sure that information isn't in the EventArgs e object?

Comment: Actually, I am hoping that information is in the EventArgs e object. I just don't know how to extract it out of there. Would it be casting the EventArgs as a DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs?

Comment: Don't ask me how this came to me but I searched for
"contextmenustrip get control"
And got the following posting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on