# How to Get datagridview Cell Value in editing mod to show in textbox(like excel)

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, binding, editing

I have a DataGridView and a textbox. I want show datagridview cell value (in editing mode)to textbox like Excel.
I'm trying something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        if (ctl == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ctl.KeyPress -= ctl_Keypress;
        ctl.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(ctl_Keypress);
    }
```

and:

```
private void ctl_Keypress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = sender as System.Windows.Forms.TextBox;
        if (box == null)
        {                
            return;
        }
        tb_currendCellValue.Text = box.Text;            
    }
```

but not working currently.
Please Help Me. thanks.

**SOLVE:** Change "KeyPress" To keyUp To work corrently.

Comment: Change "KeyPress" To keyUp To work corrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an answer to your question: [Change datagridview cell value in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033808/change-datagridview-cell-value-in-edit-mode)

I recoded the idea from the link above to your case and tested it. I created _KeyUp event within the editing control. You should add more stuff, like testing, if the editing control is type of TextBox.

[image]

C#

```
private TextBox CtrlTextbox;
private void DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (RowIdx >= 0)
    {
        CtrlTextbox = (TextBox)e.Control;
        CtrlTextbox.KeyUp += CopyText;
    }
}

private void CopyText(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox1.Text = sender.Text;
}
```

VB.NET

```
Dim CtrlTextbox As TextBox
Private Sub DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing
    If RowIdx >= 0 Then
        CtrlTextbox = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
        AddHandler CtrlTextbox.KeyUp, AddressOf CopyText
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CopyText(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = sender.Text
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Oh and there's also another fine way to achieve that - **binding**. See this article: [A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/%2FArticles%2F24656%2FA-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)
If you look at chapter *What else can you do with data binding?*, you'll see exactly your case.

Comment: this link not working currently for me. Can you add your code to the post please?

Comment: I modified the answer. The link works fine for me, I'm not sure where's the problem...

Comment: thank you. But One character is not exist!.for example datagridviewcell is 123 and textbox is 12.please help.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. Just try to replace KeyDown for KeyUp event, that'll take text *after* the key was hit.

Comment: Thank You. Worked Very Good.