# "DataGridViewCell.Value = x" does... nothing?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview, set

I'm trying to change the values of a group of selected cells when I release the ctrl key.

```
        private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
            {
                c.ReadOnly = false;
                c.Style.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
                c.ValueType = currentSymbol.GetType();
                c.Value = currentSymbol;

                dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the line "c.Value = currentSymbol;" does nothing.

c.Value remains null for no apparent reason.

I've tried everything I can think of, and the Value member just remains as null.

I'm starting to remember why I stopped using the default dataGridView, they're a frustrating nightmare to work with and never behave according to the documentation. Unfortunately I have to use one for this project.

What am I missing here? I've never seen a set command simply disobey before without throwing any kind of error.

Comment: I don't see currentSymbol being defined or initialized in your code, am I missing something?

Comment: is your DataGridView data bound? Then this might be your [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview)

Comment: currentSymbol is defined earlier in the code. DataGridView is not data bound.

Comment: what is the type of currentSymbol?

Comment: currentSymbol is a string. I can't even edit the cell values at runtime. If I type in text and hit enter, the cell just goes blank again. What is up with this crap?

Comment: If it's not databound, how did you get values in it in the first place, or how did you generate the cells?

Comment: I programatically added the rows and columns as new DataGridViewTexBoxColumns and DataGridViewRows with read only set to false.

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I programatically add a column `var c As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell();`, `c.ReadOnly = false`, `DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewColumn(c));`, `DataGridView1.Rows.Add(5)`... your key up handler works and updates the values.

Comment: fwiw I also tried with a databound DGV and your key up handler worked for that too.

Comment: So the version of the datagridview I'm using is bugged? Nice work Microsoft.

Comment: Before you jump to that conclusion, see my answer. It should also work for you with the version of .NET framework you are using.

Comment: Make sure your cell forecolor and backcolor are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: What worked for OP was to remove his DataGridVeiw and add a new one, assigning event handlers etc.

Try this example, which works for me. Make a new C# winforms app and put a datagridview.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var c = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            c.ReadOnly = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(c));
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5);
            this.dataGridView1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(dataGridView1_KeyUp);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentSymbol = "test";
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
                {
                    c.ReadOnly = false;
                    c.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                    c.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    c.ValueType = currentSymbol.GetType();
                    c.Value = currentSymbol;
                    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it also works for you there must be something else in your example which you are doing differently.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Just tried changing version, no difference, cell values cannot be edited at all. Even manually typing into them and hitting enter, the text just disappears and the cell remains blank.

Comment: OK, just went ahead an deleted the entire dataGridView and added a new one, assigned event handlers etc and now it works for no apparent reason. There a pretty fatal bug in there somewhere as I cannot for the life of me figure out why it wasn't allowing edits. Thanks for your help. Well award best answer as what you suggested is correct, there's just a bug in VS.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer to reflect your actual solution.