# Add cell value after set datasource of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

After `DataGridview` have `DataSource` from a database, I try to add column `Tax` and `Discount` in 2 way: design and code. But when I run this code:

```
public void LoadGridView()
{
    GrdReceiptDetail.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    GrdReceiptDetail.DataSource = SentoDB.usp_viewReceiptDetail(ReceiptId);
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in GrdReceiptDetail.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Name != "Check" && column.Name != "Tax" && column.Name != "Discount")
        {
            GrdReceiptDetail.Columns[column.Index].ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GrdReceiptDetail.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Index != 0)
        {
            GrdReceiptDetail.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Discount"].Value = "10";
            GrdReceiptDetail.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Tax"].Value = "10";
        }
    }
}
```

after I load the form, value in cell of 2 column `Discount` and `Tax` is blank. How can I fix it? I think when I use `DataSource`, may be `DataGridview` prevent me adding a column and value.

Comment: have you debugged this code ? Where you able to see that the grid had  columns ? Where you able to see that the grid has rows ?

Comment: yeah, grid has all value from database, and i add column to grid, i can see it in datagrid, but when i set value by those code above, it's just a blank

Comment: not used a DataGridView in some time, but in the last loop cant you just do `row.Cells["Discount"].Value = 10` ? If the column is int or decimal, then also pass it an int or decimal, not a string

Comment: yeah, i've tried it but cell still blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
if (row.Index != 0)
{
    //replace RowObject with the name of your underlying class that constitutes each 
    //row
    RowObject obj = (RowObject)row.DataBoundItem;

    //replace DiscountProperty and TaxProperty with the names of the properties on 
    //your RowObject that correspond to these values
    obj.DiscountProperty = "10";
    obj.TaxProperty = "10";
}
```

Hopefully this will work for you.  Here is a link to a similar question that elaborates more on why you should update the data this way when modifying a DataGridView with an underlying DataSource.   [Programmatically set cell value in data grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview)