# DataGridView with SuggestAppend comboBox columns and dynamic Cell assignment

Tags: winforms, powershell, datatable, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have been doing some research and could not find an answer for this, probably I'm not asking the right question or what I'm attempting might not be possible.

So, supposing I have a `DataTable` binded to a `DataGridView`, is it possible to use `SuggestAppend` in some of the data source columns?

As an example (code below), I have a `DataGridView` with columns **Employee** and **Status**. The **Status** column is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with items **Active** and **Withdraw**. The grid has a `DataTable` as source which has the same columns (**Employee & Status**), I'm using this because it's easier to export the data once modified however there might be a better way.

So, is it possible to have my `DataTable` use the columns I've created for the `DataGridView` ?

[image]

#### Code for testing:

```
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$mainForm.Text = 'Test'
$mainForm.WindowState = 'Maximized'

$bounds = ($mainForm.CreateGraphics()).VisibleClipBounds.Size

$dataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGrid.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($bounds.Width-20),($bounds.Height-140))
$dataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60)
$dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = $true
$dataGrid.SelectionMode = 0
$dataGrid.MultiSelect = $true
$dataGrid.ReadOnly = $false
$dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$dataGrid.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = 2
$dataGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = $true

$col1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
$col1.Name = 'Status'
$col1.HeaderText = 'Status'
$col1.Items.AddRange('Active','Withdraw')

$dataGrid.Columns.Add([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn],'Employee')
$dataGrid.Columns.Add($col1)

$dataGrid.Add_EditingControlShowing({
    
    $box = $_.Control -as [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]
    
    if($box)
    {
        $dataGrid.EditingControl.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDown
        $dataGrid.EditingControl.AutoCompleteMode = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode]::SuggestAppend
    }
})

$dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::Fill
#$dataGrid.Columns[-1].AutoSizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::Fill

$mainForm.Controls.Add($dataGrid)

#### Begin of DataTable as Source here

$source = @'
Employee,Status
user.example1,Active
user.example2,Withdraw
user.example3,Withdraw
user.example4,Active
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$columns = $source[0].PSobject.Properties.Name

$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

foreach($column in $columns)
{
    $i = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
    $i.DataType = [string]
    $i.ColumnName = $column
    $table.Columns.Add($i)
}

foreach($line in $source)
{
    $row = $table.NewRow()   
    foreach($column in $columns)
    {
        $row.$column = $line.$column
    }
    $table.Rows.Add($row)
}

$dataGrid.DataSource = $table

$mainForm.Add_Shown({ $mainForm.Activate() })
$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: _”So, is it possible to have my DataTable use the columns I've created for the DataGridView ?”_ … yes, this is possible. Each grid column has a property called… `DataPropertyName.` … You can set this property to the name of the column in the `DataTable` it should mate to. Example…, `dataGridView1.Columns[“Status”].DataPropertyName = “Status”;` This should display the grids bound `DataTable` column named “Status” to the column named “Status” “you” created in the grid.

Comment: In addition, you will need to set the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`’s `DataSource` to contain the items that are to be displayed in the combo box. To reduce the possibility of throwing the grids `DataError`… I suggest you loop through the grids `DataSource` “Status” column and collect all the different values in that column, then use that collection as a `DataSource` to the grids combo box column.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks a lot for this, I'm not on my Windows laptop right now, going to test tomorrow but I appreciate for taking the time to answering this. My idea is a DGV with around 50 columns and some of them should be ComboBoxColumns and others should be free text editing, do you think this is possible? I'm gathering the data from SQL and then creating the DataTable. In summary, I'm in need of a DGV that allows specific user input on some columns but is also easy for me to export the user's changes (hence why I'm using the DT binded to the DGV). Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: In a winforms `DataGridView`, you can mix and match columns as you like. In other words, you can have columns in the grid that are NOT part of the underlying data source and vice versa, you can have columns in a data source that are not displayed. I would stress, the most important aspect to mating the data source column to the grids combo box column is making sure that the combo boxes items collection contains “ALL” the items that exist in the data sources column it is mated to.

Comment: This is why I suggest that “BEFORE” you set the grids `DataSource`, you should call a method that loops through the data source’s “Status” column and makes sure there are no “bad” values in the “Status” column. If you do not make this check and “DO something” about the bad values by either removing the bad row OR adding the bad value to the combo boxes list of items… the code will crash when the grids data source is set. This check may appear as unnecessary and, in most cases, it may well be, however, this check is certainly needed to avoid a code crash because of bad data.

Comment: @JohnG thank you so much man, I really really appreciate your guidance. I added a working code example in edits, I would like to reward you with an accepted answer, if you wish you can post an answer using what you already commented and i'll mark it as accepted answer. Thanks again!

Comment: I do not have a `powershell` example that demonstrates this to post as an answer... So, I suggest you post your own answer as it may help others in the future. I am glad my suggestions helped.

Comment: I do have one question in relation to the posted solution… I may be mistaken; however, it appears the code is swallowing the grids `DataError` with … `$_.Cancel = $true` … if this is true, then I can only say this is a terrible idea. This cancelling of the grids `DataError` could lead to a sluggish UI or worse a frozen one. It is NEVER a good idea to swallow the grids `DataError.` Can you explain “why” the code is swallowing the grids `DataError`?

Comment: @JohnG Yeah that was on purpose, I haven't worked on error handling yet so I added that as placeholder so I could close the form an analyze the data to understand better how this works because if an error pops up it will popup indefinitely until I kill the process. I even got columns to have dynamically assigned values depending on the values of other columns which is something I didn't even know was possible in powershell. Winforms can be a lot of fun sometimes lol. I'll post all the code tomorrow as answer. Again, you can't imagine how much you've helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you are using Powershell for this as opposed to creating a winforms application from something like Visual Studio? Using Powershell to make a windows app, is just more work for you.

Comment: @JohnG I don't think the company I work for would allow me to install VS on the server i'm working on and for sure cannot install it on my laptop so i'm defaulting to the language I feel very confident on. I should try to learn c# sometime but i'ts pretty hard without any programming background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working thanks to [@JohnG's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842716/johng) guidance, if this is useful to you thank him not me.

#### What's included on the example code?

- `DataTable` bounded to `DataGridView`
- `DataGrid Columns` paired with `DataTable` columns
- `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with `DropDown` and `SuggestAppend`
- Dynamic cell assignment, this in theory could be done using `DataColumn's` expression but I couldn't get `IIF` conditions working on PowerShell so I used the `.Add_CellEndEdit` event to update the `DataBound` item. i.e.: `$this.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem['Code'] = '1'`

#### Example Screenshot

[image: DGV Example]

[image: DataTable Example]

#### Code Snippet

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

#### Begin of DataTable as Source here

$source = @'
Employee,Status,Code
user.example1,Active,1
user.example2,Withdraw,0
user.example3,Withdraw,0
user.example4,Active,1
user.example5,Withdraw,0
user.example6,Active,1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$columns = $source[0].PSobject.Properties.Name

$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable

$col = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$col.DataType = [string]
$col.ColumnName = 'Employee'
$table.Columns.Add($col)

$col = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$col.DataType = [string]
$col.ColumnName = 'Status'
$table.Columns.Add($col)

$col = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn
$col.DataType = [string]
$col.ColumnName = 'Code'
$table.Columns.Add($col)

foreach($line in $source)
{
    $row = $table.NewRow()
    foreach($column in $columns)
    {
        $row.$column = $line.$column
    }
    $table.Rows.Add($row)
}

##########

$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
$mainForm.Text = 'Test'
$mainForm.WindowState = 'Maximized'

$bounds = ($mainForm.CreateGraphics()).VisibleClipBounds.Size

$dataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGrid.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($bounds.Width-20),($bounds.Height-140))
$dataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60)
$dataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$dataGrid.SelectionMode = 4
$dataGrid.MultiSelect = $true
$dataGrid.ReadOnly = $false
$dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$dataGrid.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = 2
$dataGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = $true

# Pairing DataPropertyName with DataTable's column Names
$col0 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$col0.HeaderText = 'Employee'
$col0.DataPropertyName = 'Employee'
$col0.SortMode = 'NotSortable'
$dataGrid.Columns.Add($col0)

$col1=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
$col1.HeaderText = 'Status'
$col1.DataPropertyName = 'Status'
# Using DataTable 'Status' column unique values as DataSource
$col1.DataSource = $table.Status | Select-Object -Unique
$col1.SortMode = 'NotSortable'
$dataGrid.Columns.Add($col1)

$col2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$col2.HeaderText = 'Code'
$col2.DataPropertyName = 'Code'
$col2.ReadOnly = $True
$col2.SortMode = 'NotSortable'
$dataGrid.Columns.Add($col2)

$dataGrid.Add_EditingControlShowing({
    
    # Not entirely sure how this works but it works lol
    # Basically the only column that can behave as WinForms ComboBox is
    # DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. When this is True we can enable DropDown and SuggestAppend
    # to the EditingControl. This code is emulated from C# and not sure if it's the right approach
    # but still it works.

    if($_.Control -as [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox])
    {
        $this.EditingControl.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDown
        $this.EditingControl.AutoCompleteMode = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode]::SuggestAppend
    }
})

$dataGrid.Add_CellEndEdit({

    $row = $this.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem

    # I tried this to work in both ways, meaning, the value of 'Status' would
    # dynamically update the value of 'Code' and vice versa but the DGV gets super buggy
    # Seems like you need 'INotifyPropertyChanged' on the bound DataTable but couldn't
    # figure out how to make it work in PowerShell yet.
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview

    if($row.Status -eq 'Active')
    {
        $this.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem['Code'] = '1'
    }
    else
    {
        $this.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem['Code'] = '0'
    }
})

$dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]::Fill

$dataGrid.Add_DataError({

    # Error handling here
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror?view=net-5.0
    $_.Cancel = $true
})

$mainForm.Controls.Add($dataGrid)

$dataGrid.DataSource = $table

$bulkUpdateBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$bulkUpdateBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,30)
$bulkUpdateBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($dataGrid.Width-74),($dataGrid.Height+70))
$bulkUpdateBtn.Text = "Bulk Update"
$bulkUpdateBtn.Add_Click({
    
    # TO DO

})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($bulkUpdateBtn)

$mainForm.Add_Shown({ $mainForm.Activate() })
$mainForm.ShowDialog()
```