# autocomplete in datagridviewcell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a datagridview control and would like in one of the cells to make use of autocomplete.
I tried using the editcontrolshowing event but cant really get it to work.

```
$DGVtimeAttendance_EditingControlShowing = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler]{

$queryGetaLLuSERS = "SELECT CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS Employee
    FROM tbl_user"
$queryGetaLLuSERS = sql_query -Query $queryGetaLLuSERS
$getheaderText = $DGVtimeAttendance.Columns[1].HeaderText
if ($getheaderText -eq 'Employee')
{
    #$getvalueChanged = $this.Rows[$_.RowIndex].Cells[$_.ColumnIndex].value
    #Write-Host $getvalueChanged
    $autotext = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
    $autotext.AutoCompleteMode = 'Suggest'
    $autotext.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
    $autotext.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($queryGetaLLuSERS.employee)
    $DGVtimeAttendance.Controls.add($autotext)
    #$_.Control.autocompleteMode = 'Suggest'
    Write-Host $_
 }}
```

Comment: I had the same question a long time ago, hopefully it can help you find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165097/datagridview-with-datatable-as-source-and-suggestappend-combobox-columns-and-dyn

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thx for the reply sir, i will have a look at it and get back to you.

Comment: My pleasure, would love to help you but not using Windows right now hence no access to System.Windows.Forms :(

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon not only it helped i could hug you right now

Answer (score 1):

with the help from santiagos post

i changed the if statement to

```
    if ($getheaderText -eq 'Employee')
{
    $this.EditingControl.AutoCompleteMode = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode]::Suggest
    $this.EditingControl.AutoCompleteSource = [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource]::CustomSource
    $this.EditingControl.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(($queryGetaLLuSERS.employee)) #= [System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource]::CustomSource
 }
```

and worked like a charm
thx everyone and especially santiago

Comment: Glad you could solve the problem!

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want to use `Suggest` and not `SuggestAppend`? I feel the last one is a bit better