# DataGridView with simple static dropdown list

Tags: powershell, winforms, datagridview

I would like to have a simple droplist list with choice1 and choice2 to select from in this simple datagridview, but is seems impossible for me to figure out. I would also like a cancel button that just exits and an Save button that "saves the data".

```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Project = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Project.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(604,460)
$Project.Text = "My DataGridView"
$Project.TopMost = $True
$Project.MinimumSize = $Project.ClientSize
$Project.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$Project.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Create project Form Control.
$DataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView.Width = 572
$DataGridView.Height = 213
$DataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = $True
$DataGridView.ColumnCount = 2
$dataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Column0"
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Column1"
$DataGridView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16,107)
$DataGridView.SelectionMode = 'FullRowSelect'
$DataGridView.MultiSelect = $False
$DataGridView.TabIndex = 0
$DataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = $False
$DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 'Fill'
$DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $False
$DataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $True
$DataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = $True
$DataGridView.ReadOnly = $False
$DataGridView.AllowDrop = $True
$DataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 17
$DataGridView.Enabled = $True

$Project.Controls.AddRange(@($DataGridView))

$DataGridView.Rows.Add('Row1Col0','Row1Col1')
$DataGridView.Rows.Add('Row2Col0','Row2Col1')

[void]$Project.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: So, where are you stuck? What, specifically, "seems impossible to figure out"?

Comment: Well.....It is stated in the beginning:

I would like to have a simple droplist list with choice1 and choice2.
So I would like help first of all to add a dropdownlist as column 3 with a dropdown list with 2 choices for ex.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` but its unclear. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67165097/datagridview-with-suggestappend-combobox-columns-and-dynamic-cell-assignment is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes..but I need the help to implement it. I have tried, but cannot get it to work. So I'm seeking the solution

Comment: Your code doesn't show you have tried unfortunately, seems like you're asking for someone else to implement it for you. There is no attempt at adding a button or a DGV combo box column in your code.

Comment: Please show us your failed attempt and describe what goes wrong (feel free to share error messages if any)

Comment: I agreed. No of my tries worked, so removed my tries. I wasn't aware that it is requeried that the failing code should be there. I just though this was a community where help could be found. So can you help or just comment on what I miss in my question?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and if any of you can do it, please show me how?

Comment: Use the [Edit] link below your question to add the requested info