# Get one specific cell from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get one specific cell and asign it to a string from this table

| Book title | Author | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| This book | This author | This date |

I want to pick "This book" cell (Column 1, Row 2) and asign it to a string without having any selected cell.

I've tried using datatables, datasets and arrays but any of them worked

Comment: Have you tried   GridView1.Rows(15).Cells(1).Value.ToString()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516252/how-to-programmatically-set-cell-value-in-datagridview

Comment: @amirnowrozian that worked!  but aparently it's with []. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, then you can try this:

```
string str = yourGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
```

Or you can try casting DataGridView to the DataTable, and then get cell values directly from the new DataTable:

```
DataTable dt= (DataTable)yourGridView.DataSource;

string str1 = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
string str2 = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
string str3 = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
string str4 = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("Book title");
string str5 = dt.Rows[0]["Book title"].ToString();
```